# Understanding the nginx proxy_cache_path directive

Tags: nginx, configuration

Suppose I have this nginx config file

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=myCache:8m max_size=100m inactive=1h;
```

- What does the `keys_zone=myCache:8m` mean? There's not much said to it in the docs:

> In addition, all active keys and information about data are stored in a shared memory zone, whose name and size are configured by the keys_zone parameter.

- What if `proxy_cache_valid`(`12h`) is higher than the specified `inactive` value (`1h`) in `proxy_cache_path`? Which rule will it follow? e.g.

  ```
  proxy_cache_valid 200 302 12h;
  proxy_cache_valid 404 302 1h;
  ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 54):

> What does the keys_zone=myCache:8m mean?

As [documentation said](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path), nginx will keep **all active keys and information about data are stored** in a shared memory zone, whose `name` and `size` are configured by the keys_zone parameter. As a matter of completeness, lets break down per part

- `/var/cache/nginx` is the place where the actual cache stored. Inside the folder, cache file was binary file but you can easily spot the html tag inside it.
- `levels=1:2` is levels parameter sets the number of subdirectory levels in cache.
- `keys_zone=myCache:8m` was defining shared memory zone named myCache with maximum size 8 MB. It holds all active keys and *metadata* of the cache. So, whenever nginx checks if a page was cached, it consults the shared memory zone first, then seek the location of actual cache in `/var/cache/nginx` if cache exist.
- `max_size` was maximum size of cache e.g. files size on `/var/cache/nginx`.
- `inactive=1h` specify maximum inactive time cache can be stored. Cached data that are not accessed during the time specified by the `inactive` parameter get removed from the cache regardless of their freshness.

#### How cache validation and deletion works

Taken from [nginx mailing lists](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,6298,6315#msg-6315)

- Directive **proxy_cache_valid** specifies how long response will be considered valid (and will be returned without any requests to backend). After this time response will be considered "stale" and
  either won't be returned or will be depending on **proxy_cache_use_stale** setting.
- Argument **inactive** of **proxy_cache_path** specifies how long response will be stored in cache after last use. Note that even stale responses will be considered recently used if there are requests to them.

As I understand, here the pseudocode how nginx works

When request coming

```
if cache.exist AND (now() - cache.first_retrieved) < proxy_cache_valid:
    use it
else:
    retrieve from backend
    replace the old ones
```

In other process, the cache manager perform this logic

```
if (now() - cache.last_used) > inactive:
    del cache

if all-cache.size > max-size:
    del *the most inactive cache* until size < max-size
```

---

> What if proxy_cache_valid(12h) is higher than the specified inactive value (1h) in proxy_cache_path?

As long as the request and accessed the particular cache, that cache object will still valid until 12h after the object put in cache. After that, cache was considered invalid, so nginx will fetch from backend and reset the valid timer. But if object was inactive (not accessed) more than one hour - even in 12h valid-cache-period -, nginx will **delete it** because of `inactive` parameter.

Comment: "After that, cache was considered invalid, so nginx will fetch from backend and reset the valid timer." - that's interesting. So nginx fetches the request even if no user fetches it? So, for example, if inactive is `365d` and valid is `1d` then nginx will fetch the requests in the cache each day for a year even if nobody makes that request?

Comment: Nice answer, but I can't seem to find any documentation on the units of measure that we use with some of these parameters. For example, the `inactive` params takes time values but I don't see what values I can use other than `h` (how about 1 month? or 1 day? etc). And what should we be specifying with `max_size`? Bytes? Can I use 1M for 1 megabyte?

Comment: @SunilD. - here you go: http://nginx.org/en/docs/syntax.html

Comment: Confuses me a lot, isn't the request expiration tags that influence when a cached request is still valid or not ? `proxy_cache_valid` seems to also do that ?