# Nginx: 'no memory in cache keys zone', despite plenty of space

Tags: nginx, cache

I'm repeatedly seeing this error in my nginx logs:

```
[crit] 30165#0: ngx_slab_alloc() failed: no memory in cache keys zone "api-data-cache"
```

Looking at the directory used for the cache key zone, I can see it's hovering around the **326MB** mark:

```
du -s /usr/local/nginx/cache/
326652
```

However my nginx.conf specifies a `max_size` of **1GB**, so there should be plenty of room:

```
proxy_cache_path        /usr/local/nginx/cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=api-data-cache:8m max_size=1g inactive=600m;
proxy_cache_key         "$scheme$host$request_uri/$device_type$cookie_w3tc_referrer";
proxy_cache_use_stale   updating timeout http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
proxy_ignore_headers    X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
```

What could be going on here? There's plenty of disk space available (>50GB free) and after finding nothing relevant in the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path), I'm at a bit of a loss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [increase the size of shared memory](http://marc.info/?l=nginx&m=127840993820331&w=4) on `keys_zone` instead of `max_size`.

Stealing answer from [this thread](https://serverfault.com/a/641572/218590)

> **keys_zone=api-data-cache:8m** was defining shared memory zone named `api-data-cache` with maximum size 8 MB. It holds all active keys and metadata of the cache. So, whenever nginx checks if a page was cached, it consults the shared memory zone first, then seek the location of actual cache in `/usr/local/cache/nginx` if cache exist.

From [the official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_path), it says **one megabyte zone can store about 8 thousand keys**. So, depending on your application you need to increase it as needed.